# how to add waffle 1.4 dependency in Maven?

Tags: maven-3, waffle

I was trying to add dependency in my existing maven project (maven version 3) for Waffle 1.4 jars.  Can someone please help me if you have already done this before?

Found this dependency XML for Waffle version 1.3 but could not locate for 1.4.

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.waffle</groupId>
  <artifactId>waffle-testing</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Waffle 1.6 release, it is available in Maven central

https://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.github.dblock.waffle%22

Answer (score 0):

The release 1.4 couldn't be found cause it's not released. Furthermore this can be read on the [website of the project](http://waffle.codehaus.org/). Or you can check that via [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cwaffle-testing).

Comment: It looks like further waffle releases moved to http://waffle.codeplex.com/releases/view/52414.